# spring-batch ItemReader for Elasticsearch scan and scroll

Tags: spring-batch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In spring-batch, is there any support for Elasticsearch ItemReader, using the scan and scroll functionality? I do see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-elasticsearch) extension, but that's based on the normal spring-data search queries. Would be nice to have one based on the scan and scroll feature, since the batch job mostly would need to process large batch of data. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to use Cunk-Processing:http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#chunkOrientedProcessing

Comment: Any folk from Spring has some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

While there is no "native" `ItemReader` implementation for ElasticSearch, Spring Batch does provide a `RepositoryItemReader` that wraps a Spring Data `PagingAndSortingRepository`.  With this, you can use a repository definition for ElasticSearch provided by the Spring Data ElasticSearch project.

You can read more about the `RepositoryItemReader` in the Spring Batch documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemReader.html.

You can read more about the Spring Data ElasticSearch project here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.springframework.batch.item.data.AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.SearchQuery;

public class ElasticsearchItemReader<T> extends AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader<T> {
    private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;
    private final SearchQuery searchQuery;
    private String scrollId;
    private int scrollTimeinMillis = 60000;
    private Class<T> type;

    public ElasticsearchItemReader(
        final ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations,
        final SearchQuery searchQuery,
        final Class<T> type
    ) {
        this.elasticsearchOperations = elasticsearchOperations;
        this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doOpen() throws Exception {
        scrollId = elasticsearchOperations.scan(searchQuery, scrollTimeinMillis, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Iterator<T> doPageRead() {
        return elasticsearchOperations.scroll(scrollId, scrollTimeinMillis, type).iterator();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a higher version of how to write it.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

```
public class ElasticsearchItemReader<T> extends AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader<T> implements InitializingBean {

    private final ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchRestTemplate;

    private final Query query;

    private final int scrollTimeinMillis = 60000;

    private final Class<T> type;

    private final String index;

    private String scrollId;

    private boolean isFirstCall = true;


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Iterator<T> doPageRead() {
        if (isFirstCall) {
            SearchScrollHits<T> searchHits = elasticsearchRestTemplate.searchScrollStart(scrollTimeinMillis, query, type, IndexCoordinates.of(index));
            scrollId = searchHits.getScrollId();
            List<SearchHit<T>> searchHitList = searchHits.getSearchHits();
            isFirstCall = false;

            return (Iterator<T>) searchHitList.iterator();
        } else {
            SearchHitsImpl<T> searchHits = (SearchHitsImpl) elasticsearchRestTemplate.searchScrollContinue(scrollId, scrollTimeinMillis, type, IndexCoordinates.of(index));
            return (Iterator<T>) searchHits.getSearchHits().iterator();
        }

    }



    public ElasticsearchItemReader(ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchRestTemplate,
                                   Query query,
                                   Class<T> type,
                                   String index) {
        setName(getShortName(getClass()));
        this.elasticsearchRestTemplate = elasticsearchRestTemplate;
        this.query = query;
        this.type = type;
        this.index = index;
    }


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        state(elasticsearchRestTemplate != null, "An ElasticsearchOperations implementation is required.");
        state(query != null, "A query is required.");
        state(type != null, "A target type to convert the input into is required.");
    }
}
```

and itemReader code

```
public ItemReader<SearchHit<T>> reader() {

     BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery();

     NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
                .build();


     return new ElasticsearchItemReader(elasticsearchRestTemplate, query, T.class, "*");

    }
```